# Android 5.0.2 x86 on laptop problem

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, youtube

I would like to get info about an issue..I installed lollipop on my laptop (through unetbootin) and everything 's fine except one thing..videos on YouTube app do not play..they keep loading and loading..and if I set a lower quality,all I get is that screen..!!

[image: red/black screen]

Can anyone help on that issue??

Comment: Can you please send a link to this android iso?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4VR-WNTOX0qVnkyWExEZHdLTms/view